# How to update a table in sql using data from another one?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, inner-join, updates

I have two tables and I want to insert a data from the old table into a new one, how can I do this using inner join?

**TABLE1**

[image]

**TABLE2**

[image]

I tried this:

```
 update User
 set nickname= NICKNAME
 FROM BASICDATA2 INNER JOIN LegacyId   
 ON USERID= newIdLegacy  INNER JOIN User 
 ON newId = newIdLegacy  
 WHERE NICKNAME IS NOT NULL
```

But it doesn't make any changes, how can I do this?

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) to understand why

Comment: [**Tips for your SQL Question**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056)

Comment: Is kind of confusing what is table and what is data

Answer (score 0):

Update is only for updating rows that already exist. You want to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 SELECT Nickname FROM TABLE2 T2 WHERE T2.Nickname IS NOT NULL
```